# Vaadin 14 Lazy Loading Fetch iterations - Not what we expect

Tags: grid, vaadin14

We are attempting to use the CallbackDataProvider class to perform lazy loading using a Grid component.
Our data source is using JPA implementation with pagination
Setting a page size = 20 running a query that would return 200 rows in the result set the callback seems to perform only 2 fetches, the first fetch for 20 rows, the second for the remaining 180 rows

This is not what we expected, we are expecting 20 rows on each fetch or for the 200 rows, 10 fetch of 20 rows each.
Is our expectation incorrect here?
Using this paradigm if there are 1000 or 2000 rows in the result set, I don't see how lazy loading is of any benefit here since fetching 980 rows on the second fetch defeat the lazy load purpose

Anyone have a similar experience or is there something we are missing?

Answer (score 0):

The actual buffersize of the loaded data is determined by the components web client part. Pagesize is only the initial parameter. The default value of the pagesize is 50, which leads in normal circumstances Grid to load 100 items at the time. If web client determines that pagesize is too small based on it visual size, it will larger buffer. Usually pagesizes as small as 20 do not work well.